# Set panel visiblity on Escape key press

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have a windows form and it has two panels. Main panel and popup panel.When specific button click main panel will disable and popup panel will be visible.
My question is when user press escape key i want to set visibility of popup panel to false and enable main panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool bPanelFocus;
private void cancelButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (popuppanel.Visible == true && bPanelFocus)
    {
        popuppanel.Visible = false;
        mainpanel.Visible = true;
        return;
    }

    //your code for the cancel button
}
```

Since you have a cancel button on the form, it will trigger the click event on that button when you press the Esc button. On your cancel button's click event, add a validation to check if the pop up panel is visible, also you might need a flag to check if the user has focus on the panel otherwise proceed with the cancel button's procedures.

Comment: it works fine, but my form has set cancel button, can i prevent firing cancel button event

Comment: Hmm maybe you can handle the `KeyUp` event on the PopUp panel.

Comment: panel dont have KeyUp event